# Mingw use malloc for struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I just encountered a malloc trouble in my assignment
//This is my header file

```
struct vertex_t {
    int id;
    char *label;

    /* A list of vertices representing incoming edges */
    List in;
    /* A List of vertices representing outgoing edges */
    List out;
};
struct graph_t {
    /* Number of vertices */
    int order;
    /* Numb er of edges */
    int size;
    Vertex vertices;
};
```

//We are not allowed to change the header file above. In my main file, how can i malloc the vertices in the graph?

```
Graph new_graph(int order) {
    Graph graph;
    int i;
    graph=NULL;
    graph=(Graph)malloc(sizeof(Graph));
    assert(graph);
    graph->order=order;
    graph->size=0;
    graph->vertices=(Vertex*)malloc((order+100000)*sizeof(Vertex));//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!this line!!!!
    for(i=0;i<order;i++){
        graph->vertices[i].label=(char*)malloc(MAX_LINE_LEN*sizeof(char));
        graph->vertices[i].in=NULL;
        graph->vertices[i].out=NULL;
    }
    return graph;
}
```

I only can add the extreme large number in the malloc to prevent memory leak.

Comment: Not an answer but [don't typecast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). like `graph=(Graph)malloc(sizeof(Graph));` and others.

Comment: What is type `Vertex`?

Comment: Where is the `typedef` for `Vertex`??

Comment: Great minds think alike...

Comment: What is the question.

Comment: What is List?  Have a look at using realloc.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to see all errors as you don't give a complete program, but as far as I see you made an error with this lines:

```
graph=(Graph)malloc(sizeof(Graph));
graph->vertices=(Vertex*)malloc((order+100000)*sizeof(Vertex));
```

`Graph` and `Vertex` seems to be a pointer type, so you should do this instead:

```
graph = malloc(sizeof(struct graph_t));
graph->vertices = malloc((order)*sizeof(struct vertex_t));
```

I assume `Vertex` is the pointer type associated to `struct vertex_t` and `Graph` is the pointer type associated to `struct graph_t`in your headers.

We don't use `malloc()` to allocate memory for the pointer itself but for the data it is pointing. So the size depends on the data. If `pType` is a pointer type such as `char *`, `int *` or `struct my_struct *`, `sizeof(pType)` will allways be the same (8 for a 32-bit program or 16 for a 64-bit program for instance).

Answer (score 0):

```
 Graph graph;
 graph = (Graph)malloc(sizeof(Graph));
```

This is the first problem. Observe correct patterns:

```
struct Foo { ... };

Foo* foo = malloc(sizeof(Foo)); // one way
foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo)); // the other way, handy when you are not sure what your type is
```

Note how you pass in the size of the *struct* and get back a *pointer*.

Same thing happens with the second allocation:

```
graph->vertices = (Vertex*)malloc((order+100000)*sizeof(Vertex));
```

In your code both `Graph` and `Vertex` are pointers, but you want to allocate pointed-to structures, not pointers.

In addition, you cast the result to `Vertex*` but assign it to `Vertex`. This should have provoked a compiler warning. You must read, understand and eliminate all warnings, no exception. I recommend setting up your compiler so that it treats warnings as errors.